# How to send back 2d int array as intent

Tags: android

I want to send back a int[][] array to the main activity. I have searched but couldn't find any simple and straight way, is there a way to send and receive int[][] as intent?

Comment: Wrap up the 2d int array in a POJo and pass the pojo as Intent

Comment: As Santanu said, put it in an object and make that object serializable. Then you can send that object in intent. But if your 2d array is a monster array like million values, serializable is not a good way for performance btw.

Comment: Thanks. I thought with new version they may have make it simpler but it looks ur suggested way and making static class are only current options. If anyone has any other more direct approach plz tell.